# Combine three queries as one result

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

I'm relatively new to SQL and I'm trying to make my workflow more efficient.

In particular, I am currently pulling data a MS SQL database through three queries like this in R.

```
select ID, 'active' as Indicator_1 from table1
where STATUS = '2' and type = '1'
```

This returns a table as such:

```
ID  Indicator_1
01    active
02    active
03    active
   ...
```

Than, I pull the same query with a **different type value**.

```
select ID, 'active' as Indicator_1 from table1
where STATUS = '2' and type = '50'
```

This returns a table as such:

```
ID  Indicator_2
01    active
03    active
04    active
   ...

select ID, 'active' as Indicator_1 from table1
where STATUS = '2' and type = '20'
```

This returns a table as such:

```
ID  Indicator_3
01    NA/Blank
03    active
04    active
   ...
```

Than, I will load the data in R as a dataframe, and join the tables.

I understand this is inefficient. 
What I want to do, **the expected result** is ask a query that returns a combined result.

```
ID  Indicator_1   Indicator_2  Indicator_3
01    active        active       NA/Blank
03    active       NA/Blank      active
04    Na/Blank      active       active
   ...
```

Any suggestions how to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Add all the 3 queries,result and your expected result.

Comment: `type in ('1', '50')` should suffice -- you can then reshape the data in R. If you insist on doing that part in SQL (e.g., if the result won't fit in RAM), you can use outer joins.

Comment: I edited the question with more info. Hope it more precise.

Comment: I do not understand how can `select ID, 'active' as Indicator_1 from table1
where STATUS = '2' and type = '20'` return a string `Na/Blank` as a result value in the second column in SQL Server?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal because the result was just for illustration. Its not the actual result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try This

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
       ID, 
       Indicator_1 = CASE [Type]
                       WHEN 1 THEN 'Active'
                    ELSE NULL END,
       Indicator_2 = CASE [Type]
                       WHEN 50 THEN 'Active'
                    ELSE NULL END
       FROM dbo.table1
          WHERE [status] = '2'
             AND [Type] IN ('1','50')
)
SELECT
    Id,
    Indicator_1 = COALESCE(MAX(Indicator_1),'NA/Blank'),
    Indicator_2 = COALESCE(MAX(Indicator_2),'NA/Blank')
    FROM CTE
       GROUP BY Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query ! 
simply combining the queries using UNION clause

```
    SELECT  
           ID                     ,
          'active' AS Indicator_1 ,
           null    AS Indicator_2 , 
           null    AS Indicator_3 
    FROM   table1
    WHERE  STATUS = '2' 
    AND    type = '1'

    UNION

    SELECT 
           ID                     ,
           null    AS Indicator_1 , 
          'active' AS Indicator_2 ,
           null    AS Indicator_3 
    FROM   table1
    WHERE  STATUS = '2' 
    AND    type = '50'

    UNION

    SELECT 
           ID                     ,
           null    AS Indicator_1 ,
           null    AS Indicator_2 , 
          'active' AS Indicator_3 
    FROM   table1
    WHERE  STATUS = '2'  
    AND    type = '20'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do an easy query in SQL and then modify the data.frame in R to obtain your wanted result.

Easy query:

```
select ID, 'active','type' as Indicator_1 from table1
where STATUS = '2' and type in ('1','50','20')
```

Your result in R will be something like "db" data.frame like this:

```
ID<-c(1,2,3,1,5,2)
Indicator<-c("active","active","active","active","active","active")
Status<-c(1,1,50,50,50,20) db<-data.frame(cbind(ID,Indicator,Status))

  ID Indicator Status
  1    active      1
  2    active      1
  3    active     50
  1    active     50
  5    active     50
  2    active     20
```

Now you can process the data.frame

```
db_merge<-merge(x=db[db$Status==1,],y=db[db$Status==50,],by="ID",all=T)
db_merge<-merge(x=db_merge,y=db[db$Status==20,],by="ID",all=T)
```

Your result:

```
ID Indicator.x Status.x Indicator.y Status.y Indicator Status
1      active        1      active       50      <NA>   <NA>
2      active        1        <NA>     <NA>    active     20
3        <NA>     <NA>      active       50      <NA>   <NA>
5        <NA>     <NA>      active       50      <NA>   <NA>
```

Comment: I was already doing this. But specifying the query correctly in SQL I believe is the better method here.

Comment: I agree with you! This is only a different (less efficient) approach.